# What colorscheme settings control text background colors in Vim (terminal version)?

Tags: bash, vim

I run `vim` in a full-screen `bash` terminal with transparency enabled. (This is a nice setup for a laptop--almost makes me not miss my multi-monitor rig when I'm away from my desk.)

The trouble I'm running into is that most color schemes, such as the otherwise excellent `desert256`, set some kind of highlighting color behind the text, usually black. The net effect is a mostly transparent terminal with blocks of black behind each line of code, obscuring whatever they are in front of.

Some of the default color schemes, such as `elflord`, do not do this. The background remains consistently transparent.

Is there a setting I can execute in my `.vimrc` after setting the `colorscheme` to remove the text background color? I use a `pathogen` plugin to refresh my color schemes from GitHub, so I don't want to edit my local copies.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Found the answer. I added this to my `.vimrc` after the `colorscheme` line:

```
hi Normal ctermbg=NONE
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer. For reference, I also had to make sure this was placed after 'syntax on' as well.

Comment: How do you add a text background color? I tried `hi Normal ctermbg=#A0A0A0`